# Telegram API - получить файл, не сохраняя его физически

Tags: java, telegram

Доброй ночи.

Пишу клиент Telegram под Android на базе библиотеки [Kotlogram](https://github.com/badoualy/kotlogram), и столкнулся с со следующей проблемой. Я должен подгрузить список диалогов для пользователя, этот кейс есть в примерах данной библиотеки. Но, помимо самих чатов, мне нужно получить и их изображения для отображения в списке. Весь вечер пытаюсь решить эту проблему, но ничего не выходит. Максимальный результат, которого я смог добиться - сохранить изображение локально. Получилось это у меня следующим образом:

```
TelegramClient client = Kotlogram.getDefaultClient(application, new ApiStorage());
TLUserFull user = User.getUser(client, telegramMessageEvent.getFromId());
TLPhoto photo = user.getProfilePhoto().getAsPhoto();
MediaInput mediaInput = TLMediaUtilsKt.getMediaInput(TLMediaUtilsKt.getMaxSize(photo.getSizes()));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/TEMP", "test.png"));
client.downloadSync(mediaInput.getInputFileLocation(), mediaInput.getSize(), fos);
```

Но меня это не устраивает. Наилучшим вариантом было бы получение прямой ссылки на это изображение. Я так понимаю, в Telegram API нельзя сделать как в Telegram Bot API через ссылку вида:

```
https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>
```

Порывшись в сети, я нашел один вариант из другой библиотеки:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes().getData()));
```

где `file` - `TLFile`.

В самой же библиотеке есть метод, например,

```
client.getUserPhoto(user);
```

который возвращает как раз объект типа `TLFile`.
Не знаю, сработал бы данный вариант или нет, но вышеуказанный метод падает с ошибкой

> 400: LIMIT_INVALID

Я так понимаю, что данная ошибка означает то, что идет запрос на файл, весящий больше 1Мб. И в таком случае его необходимо бы разбить на части, но такой функционал я нашел только в методе

```
client.downloadSync()
```

По умолчанию стоит 512Кб.

Насколько я посмотрел, библиотеки на основе Telegram API под различные платформы схожи по своей структуре. Поэтому я хотел бы узнать, каким образом можно получить прямую ссылку на изображение через Telegram API или, на крайний случай, объект, содержащий само изображение. Сохранение файла в память для его дальнейшего считывания меня вообще не устраивает.

Заранее спасибо.